# Xcode does not show all folders on a SwiftPM project

Tags: xcode

I am opening a swiftPM project with Xcode. Under the `Examples` directory, only one subfolder is visible in Xcode, while there are 8 folders available in the Finder.

I tried to reset all Xcode settings and caches but it does not change anything.
I also try to "Add Files" or drag'n drop files to Xcode but the missing directories are not added.

Any idea why it happens and how to fix this ?

View in the Finder:

[[image: Project view in the finder]]

View in Xcode:

[image: Project view in Xcode]

Answer (score 0):

Follow up for history and archives.  The `Examples` directories having a `Package.swift` file do not show up in Xcode.

I guess Xcode tries to avoid package conflict. It does not handle sub-projects very well.